# Windows Defender Firewall has blocked some features of Android Studio

Tags: android, windows, android-studio

Should I allow the application to access? Which choice should I choose if I allow it to access, private networks or public networks or both? Thanks!

Comment: You can trust Android Studio if you download it from the right source. So don't worry about that just allow it.

Comment: Thanks for you reply! Yes, I downloaded it from the main site. So, I should check both choices?

Comment: Of course, it won't harm your PC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should allow both,   as it needs to download 3rd party libraries  from time to time.